# Explain how you might find a vector $\bar{X} ̄$ such that $M\bar{X}− V$ is as small as possible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let M be an $m \times n$ matrix, $X$ a column vector of n unknowns and V a given column vector with m entries. Moreover, suppose V is not in the span of the columns of M. Does MX = V have any solutions? If not, explain how you might find a vector $\bar{X} ̄$ such that $M\bar{X}− V$ is as small as possible. Assume that only the zero vector is in the kernel of M and your answer should first address the question “what does it mean for a vector to be small”

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common metrics to describe a vector to be "small" or "large" is its [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm). If we use the Euclidean norm of the vector as the metric, then you are looking for a vector $X$ that minimizes $\|MX-V\|_2^2$. This vector can be shown to be equal to 
$$X = M^{+}V,$$
where $M^+$ is the pseudo-inverse of $M$. See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse for more details.